# Why EMR with spark step fails when spark-env.export has a variable with cron expression inside?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

Resume:

In EMR Spark setting a configuration of spark-env.export.myvariable with a cron expression like: "cron(0 6 * * ? *)" make all spark-env.export variables don't be exported to the machine.

Details:

I'm running an EMR 6.15.0 with spark 3.4.1, and if I have a configuration of spark-env.export.myvariable with a cron expression like: "cron(0 6 * * ? *)" when my step try to access environment variables I set with spark-env.export the step does not find any variable

**Why this happens?**